Maui radio button border color not visible in dark mode?
Trying to fix an issue I'm seeing on both Android & iOS in dark mode where the border of my radio button is not showing up. Once the button is pressed, the filled circle shows up for the checked selection, but I need both unchecked radio button circles to be there so the user knows the buttons are there. Anyone know how to get radio button formatting to work correctly in dark mode?
Here's the xaml for the buttons:
<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadio0No" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="No" BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="{StaticResource AppMainColor}" FontSize="Body" TextColor="{StaticResource AppMainColor}" IsChecked="false"  CheckedChanged="OnRadioButton0CheckedChanged" />
<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadio0Yes" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Yes" BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="{StaticResource AppMainColor}" FontSize="Body" TextColor="{StaticResource AppMainColor}" IsChecked="false" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" CheckedChanged="OnRadioButton0CheckedChanged"/>

Result in light mode:

Result in dark mode:

I've also tried setting the border color in Styles.xaml as well as specifying it for dark mode, but this didn't change anything:
<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
     <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource AppMainColor}, Dark={StaticResource AppMainColor}}" />
     ...
</Style>


What happens when you click on it does it work?

@FreakyAli it works, they are just white brush drawn on white background :)

@jess https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15795 just notice the statement "low priority"...

@jess so did you find a solution yet?

@FreakyAli Nope, still trying to figure it out

@jess are you willing to use libraries?

I did a test on my side, and I could reproduce this problem on my side. We should avoid using colors that are close to or the same as the background, otherwise we will run into problems just as you mentioned.
So, if I removed code BackgroundColor="White", and this problem will not recur in dark mode.
My test code is as follows:
<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadio0No" Content="No"  FontSize="Body" TextColor="Black" IsChecked="false"/>


Unfortunately, I need to specify the BackgroundColor otherwise it turns grey/black on some devices in dark mode and looks really bad. I want the background to be white and the radio button to be a dark color, so it should show up very clearly

You can specify the BackgroundColor, but BackgroundColor and the BorderColor color should not be similar, otherwise the problem you said will still appear.

Well this is another Maui bug then because my BackgroundColor and BorderColor are very different

Could you please post the link of this Maui bug as you mentioned above?

I don't have a link for you, see above for the screenshots/description of issue. I think it's a bug because implementing these properties isn't showing up correctly/at all in the UI

the best way: you can set light mode default in App file



if (Current != null)
{
    Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
}



